"Package natbib Warning: Citation `' multiply defined" and "I didn't find a database entry for" in a cross-reference (with "zref-clever")
Question.
I am working within a cross-referenced environment, i.e. I cross-reference tables, figures and citations (with "zref-clever"), between a main.tex file and a supplementary.tex file.
How can I solve the following warnings that I get when I compile the main.tex file?
(1) Package natbib Warning: Citation `Vlemmings2024' multiply defined.
‪./output.aux‬
You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \label{...} labels only one item.
Learn more

(2) Package natbib Warning: There were multiply defined citations.
‪./main.tex‬
You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \label{...} labels only one item.
Learn more

(3) I didn't find a database entry for "Liu2024"

Minimal Working Example (MWE) based on @gusbrs solution_1 and solution_2.
We can reproduce the exact same warnings with the following codes (related to supplementary.tex, suppl.bib, main.tex, and main.bib):
supplementary.tex
\documentclass{article}

\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{zref-titleref} % after (sub)caption
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\zcsetup{cap,noabbrev,nameinlink,
  countertype={
    section=suppsection,
    table=supptable,
    figure=suppfigure,
    % And others you might need...
  },
}
% At begindocument since zref-clever sets this up in the compat module.
\AddToHook{begindocument}{\zcsetup{countertype={subfigure=suppfigure}}}

\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Section ,
    name-sg = section ,
    Name-pl = Sections ,
    name-pl = sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Figure ,
    name-sg = figure ,
    Name-pl = Figures ,
    name-pl = figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Table ,
    name-sg = table ,
    Name-pl = Tables ,
    name-pl = tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
The results shown in \zcref{my_subfigure_a_supp,my_subfigure_b_supp} are similar to those ones presented in \cite{Vlemmings2024}. They support the theory of \cite{Liu2024}.

\section{Supplementary section about figures}
\label{supp_figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (4.5cm,-0.5cm) {a};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_subfigure_a_supp}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (4.5cm,-0.5cm) {b};
        \phantomcaption\label{my_subfigure_b_supp}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \end{subcaptiongroup}
    \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
    \caption{
    Caption of my supplementary figure :-). Here we have subfigure
    \subref*{my_subfigure_a_supp}, and subfigure
    \subref*{my_subfigure_b_supp}.
    }
    \label{my_figure_supp}
\end{figure}


\bibliography{suppl}


\end{document}


where
suppl.bib
@article{Vlemmings2024,
   author = {Vlemmings, Wouter and Khouri, Theo and Bojnordi Arbab, Behzad and De Beck, Elvire and Maercker, Matthias},
   title = {One month convection timescale on the surface of a giant evolved star},
   journal = {Nature},
   volume = {633},
   number = {8029},
   pages = {323-326},
   ISSN = {1476-4687},
   DOI = {10.1038/s41586-024-07836-9},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-024-07836-9},
   year = {2024},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{Liu2024,
   author = {Liu, Cheng and Yang, Yi and Chen, Hao and Spanopoulos, Ioannis and Bati, Abdulaziz S. R. and Gilley, Isaiah W. and Chen, Jianhua and Maxwell, Aidan and Vishal, Badri and Reynolds, Robert P. and Wiggins, Taylor E. and Wang, Zaiwei and Huang, Chuying and Fletcher, Jared and Liu, Yuan and Chen, Lin X. and De Wolf, Stefaan and Chen, Bin and Zheng, Ding and Marks, Tobin J. and Facchetti, Antonio and Sargent, Edward H. and Kanatzidis, Mercouri G.},
   title = {Two-dimensional perovskitoids enhance stability in perovskite solar cells},
   journal = {Nature},
   volume = {633},
   number = {8029},
   pages = {359-364},
   ISSN = {1476-4687},
   DOI = {10.1038/s41586-024-07764-8},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-024-07764-8},
   year = {2024},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{zref-titleref} % after (sub-)caption
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}

\zexternaldocument{supplementary}
\externaldocument{supplementary}

\zcsetup{cap,noabbrev,nameinlink}
\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = suppsection ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary section ,
    name-sg = supplementary section ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary sections ,
    name-pl = supplementary sections ,
  type = suppfigure ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary figure ,
    name-sg = supplementary figure ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary figures ,
    name-pl = supplementary figures ,
  type = supptable ,
    Name-sg = Supplementary table ,
    name-sg = supplementary table ,
    Name-pl = Supplementary tables ,
    name-pl = supplementary tables ,
  % And others you might need...
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
The results shown in \zcref{my_subfigure_a_supp,my_subfigure_b_supp} are similar to those ones presented in \cite{Vlemmings2024}. They support the theory of \cite{Liu2024}, but not the theory of \cite{Wagner2024}.

\bibliography{main}

\end{document}


where
main.bib
@article{Vlemmings2024,
   author = {Vlemmings, Wouter and Khouri, Theo and Bojnordi Arbab, Behzad and De Beck, Elvire and Maercker, Matthias},
   title = {One month convection timescale on the surface of a giant evolved star},
   journal = {Nature},
   volume = {633},
   number = {8029},
   pages = {323-326},
   ISSN = {1476-4687},
   DOI = {10.1038/s41586-024-07836-9},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-024-07836-9},
   year = {2024},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{Wagner2024,
   author = {Wagner, Jonathan and Carvajal, Alonso I. and Bracher, Andreas and Beck, Florian and Wan, William and Bohn, Stefan and Körner, Roman and Baumeister, Wolfgang and Fernandez-Busnadiego, Ruben and Hartl, F. Ulrich},
   title = {Visualizing chaperonin function in situ by cryo-electron tomography},
   journal = {Nature},
   volume = {633},
   number = {8029},
   pages = {459-464},
   ISSN = {1476-4687},
   DOI = {10.1038/s41586-024-07843-w},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-024-07843-w},
   year = {2024},
   type = {Journal Article}
}


Ommo, I can only offer the same advice as in your last question: when you are using xr (or zref-xr) you need to be mindful of what you are importing and that the things make sense in the document you are importing to. Regarding your warning messages: i) I didn't find a database entry for "Liu2024" Is there an entry for Liu2024 in main.bib? ii) There were multiply defined citations. Please check the xr documentation about citations. iii) You have used the same label more than once. I cannot reproduce that.

Thanks for your comment @gusbrs :-)
About point (i), i.e. I didn't find a database entry for "Liu2024", I just added that reference to main.bib. However, now, I get both Package natbib Warning: Citation `Vlemmings2024' multiply defined. and Package natbib Warning: Citation `Liu2024' multiply defined.. This means that, if I add the same reference in both main.bib and in suppl.bib, I get that warning... I still do not know (after checking the xr docs) how to remove that warning...

I mean, when I need the same citation in both main.tex and supplementary.tex files, should I add it to both main.bib and suppl.bib files, or not? If yes, I then get the warning Package natbib Warning: Citation `' multiply defined. for every citation that is defined in both .tex files... Also, I cannot find a way to add a citation in just one .tex file and then to call it in the other .tex file, without getting a warning message...

Ommo, xr also imports citations by default. You need to decide whether you want to do so or not. If you don't, disable it in \externaldocument and make sure each bib file contains all the citations you need. If you do, then you cannot have the same entry (key...) in both bib files, otherwise you get duplicates. In the latter case, note that entries imported by xr are only available on the latex side of things, bibtex does not see them, so bibtex will warn you that I didn't find a database entry for ....

Ah OK, thanks a lot :-) :-) :-)

At the end, I opted for \externaldocument[nocite]{supplementary} and I just made sure that all the reference are added to both .bib files... In that way, I do not get the warnings and everything looks cleaner :-)

Are you sure that \externaldocument[nocite]{supplementary} is really what you mean? Read the manual carefully...

...well, \externaldocument[nocite]{} looks like working for those few references that are present in both .tex files... Indeed, I do not get the Package natbib Warning: There were multiply defined citations. or any of the Package natbib Warning: Citation `' multiply defined. warnings anymore.... and the citations look correct.... :-)
